# Develop Android app and Java app that both interact with same database

Tags: java, android

Hello people I'm a web developer who wants to write some Android apps. I have some experience in object oriented programming concepts and it won't be difficult to get familiar with Java. Anyways the application I want to write has two parts. One is a mobile client that has read permissions from the database, the other is a desktop client that will update and modify data in database. The database itself shall be contained in a server (just another desktop) proper to the office. Each office will have this configuration and the databases from each office will be collected to update the main database (collection of databases from all offices) which would be stored on a remote server.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. If it is possible, can you provide some guidance for a fellow code writer?

Comment: The question is too broad for this site. Please read the guide : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. What you need is Volley to handle your API calls. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278866/android-volley-quickstart/17278867#17278867) to get started.

Comment: thank you bro im one step closer to implementing my idea properly